# What is the return type of a stackalloc espression?

Tags: c#, unsafe, stackalloc

I'm playing with `stackalloc` and finding a lot of weirdness in its return type. Here are some examples using `stackalloc<float>`:

**1.** Implicit typing returns `float*`:

```
var a = stackalloc float[1];//a is float*
```

**2.** Declaring a `float*` and setting it later using `stackalloc` doesn't compile:

```
    float* a;
    a = stackalloc float[1];//CS8346 conversion of a stackallock expression of type 'float' to type 'float*' is not possible
```

**3.** Declaring the `float*` at the same time as initialization works just fine:

```
float* a = stackalloc float[1];
```

**4.** A similar behavior happens for `Span<float>`

This works just fine:

```
 Span<float> a = stackalloc float[1];
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
        Span<float> a; 
        a = stackalloc float[1];//CS8353 A result of a stackalloc expression of type 'Span<float>' cannot be used in this context because it may be exposed outside of the containing method
```

**5.** What makes this whole situation even weirder is that there is no implicit conversion between `Span<float>` and `float*` or vise versa.

**So what exactly is `stackalloc float[1]` returning? And why is the above behavior ocurring?**

This code was written using VS 2019 C# version 9.0, .NET 5.

Comment: Yes, the language specification demands this.  stackalloc can only appear as the initializer for a local variable.  Perfectly sensible, it is not anything like the zero initialization that .NET normally applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [C# 6 draft specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#stack-allocation) `stackalloc`:

> In an unsafe context, a local variable declaration ([Local variable declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#local-variable-declarations)) may include a stack allocation initializer which allocates memory from the call stack.

i.e. it can be used only in declarations which you have called "inline".

As per [language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc) `stackalloc` does not have single defined return type but "allocates a block of memory on the stack" and then:

> You can assign the result of a stackalloc expression to a variable of one of the following types:
>
> - Beginning with C# 7.2, `System.Span<T>` or `System.ReadOnlySpan<T>`
> - A pointer type

Some interesting extra links:

- [C# - All About Span: Exploring a New .NET Mainstay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/january/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay#what-about-the-c-language-and-compiler) by Stephen Toub.
- CS8353 dicussion on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25118)
- [Why does a zero-length stackalloc make the C# compiler happy to allow conditional stackallocs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67289057/why-does-a-zero-length-stackalloc-make-the-c-sharp-compiler-happy-to-allow-condi)